# Detect and dtermine the width of a human hand in opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I want to detect a human hand and determin its width. Is there a way to it in openCV, or any technique to do that.

I've tried searching google but couldn't find any solution.

[image]

My segmentation result:

[image]

Comment: Yes there is a way. There is always a way. Please read [ask].

Comment: I have detected the hand place the edges around it using a contor now how can i find the width. If you can help. It will be really great.
I'm in serious problem if you can help please let me know i'll will read those etiquette.

Comment: if you want help provide images and your code. we don't like to guess. what is the width of a hand by your definition? where to measure? provide a sketch

Comment: The line in black colour over the hand represents my defination of the width "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxP3s-9QVdsEQTNpN0lwR0FlZDA/view?usp=sharing"

And till now i have applied a skin detection algo and get this result
"https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxP3s-9QVdsERFZWdnN5bngxOUE/view?usp=sharing"
And please me with that distance

Comment: I added the images for you. I'll leave it up to you to write a nice question around them. add your code, describe the problem. describe how the position of that black line is defined. explain what you have done so far. to me your segmentation result looks pretty bad.

Comment: Thanks for hanging with me so far, detecting hand is not a big issue. It's just one or two functions calls in opencv. The real point where I'm stuck for almost a day is to detect the palm and determine it's width. It would be appreciated if you could atlease point me in a right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As your question is too broad to be answered without writing a 10 page essay I'll give you a few ideas at least.

Option 1:
Detect the finger tips and fit a hand model (there should be plenty of papers, open source code and other resources available online that do hand and gesture detection). you can then position your line using that hand model.

Option 2:
The dimension you are looking for should be the shortest cross section of any hand. Place a scan line over your hand, rotate it around it's centroid and measure the distance between the transition hand - background on both ends. Then pick the minimum. Make sure you have the right rotation center. Maybe cut the fingers of using morphological operations to move the centroid a bit further down so you don't get a wrong measurement.

Option 3: Estimate the width of the hand by its total size. Human proportions usually follow some rules. See if you can find some correlation between that measure and other hand features. If you don't need too exact measures (your image resoltion suggests this) this should be the quickest and easiest solution.

There are many other options. Take a ruler and your hand and start thinking. Or do more research on gesture recognition in general. I'm sure you can apply may things they use to get your width.